# Plusquamperfekt mit einem Nomen im Passiv

Tags: verb, past, pluperfect

Ich lerne das Plusquamperfekt. Verstehe aber nicht folgendes (Beispiel):

> Die am Telefon sagten mir, dass der Vertrag abgelehnt wurde.

Auf Englisch würde ich sagen *they told me...it had been rejected* which is clearly a pluperfect. Aber im Deutschen sieht die o.g. Phrase nicht als Plusquamperfekt aus.

*Die am Telefon sagten* (Vergangenheit). Dann kommt einen Hauptsatz, wo die Ablehnung sogar früher passiert und außerdem steht den Nomen im Passiv!

In Passiv [wird es mit einer Form von *war → werden* gebildet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plusquamperfekt#Im_Deutschen_im_Passiv) . So, überlege ich:

> Die am Telefon sagten mir, dass der Vertrag abgelehnt worden war.

ist richtig, oder?

Comment: Deine Überlegung beim zweiten Beispiel ist korrekt. Leider neigt man im Deutschen dazu, beim Plusquamperfekt etwas unpräzise zu sein und so hat sich größtenteils „wurde“ statt „worden war“ eingebürgert.

Comment: Die Zeitenfolge im Deutschen ist in der allgemeinen Sprachpraxis weit weniger restriktiv als die im Englischen. Vorzeitige Ereignisse müssen nicht notwendigerweise auch mit "vorzeitigem Tempus" ausgedrückt werden. Im Deutschen ist das kein Fehler.

Comment: Ausserdem ist das indirekte Rede - Vollkommen richtig wäre: *Die am Telefon sagten mir, dass der Vertrag abgelehnt worden sei/wäre.*

Comment: @tofro Bei dass-Sätzen ist auch der Indikativ zulässig: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Modus-nach-wissen-erfahren-u

Comment: @tavkomann Ich weiß. Das ist der Unterschied zwischen "richtig" und "vollkommen richtig".

Comment: @tofro, wenn die Ablehnung vom Sprecher als Tatsache mitgeteilt wird, finde ich den Konjunktiv nicht richtiger.

Answer (score 2):

Beide Sätze sind grammatisch richtig. Welchen der beiden Sätze ein deutscher 
Sprecher wählen würde, hängt davon ab, was als nächstes passiert und in welchem 
zeitlichen Abstand sich die Ereignisse abspielen.

Der erste Satz wäre auf Englisch eher 'they told me ... it was rejected'.

Der zweite Satz kommt 'had been rejected' näher, doch im Deutschen wird
seltener auf das Plusquamperfekt zurückgegriffen, weil es länger ist und 
umständlich klingen kann. Man würde es im Alltag nur dann einsetzen, wenn
zu den beiden Ereignissen 'Telefonat' und 'Ablehnung' noch ein drittes
Ereignis hinzukäme und man nun den zeitlichen Zusammenhang zwischen dem 
zweiten und dritten Ereignis (das wie das zweite Ereignis in der Vergangenheit liegt)
verdeutlichen will.

> Die am Telefon sagten mir, dass der Vertrag abgelehnt wurde, als der
>   Blitz einschlug.

Ablehnung und Blitzeinschlag liegen hier zeitlich dicht zusammen.

> Die am Telefon sagten mit, dass der Vertrag abgelehnt worden war, als
>   der Blitz einschlug.

Als der Blitz einschlägt ist die Vertragsablehnung schon (lange) vorbei.

Würde also ein deutscher Sprecher deinen zweiten Beispielsatz in einem Gespräch verwenden, hätte der Gesprächspartner die Erwartungshaltung, dass noch etwas passiert war, so dass die Frage 'Ja, und dann?' zu erwarten ist, falls der Satz alleine steht.

Answer (score -3):

`abgelehnt worden war` bedeutet:  Der Vertrag wurde abgelehnt, könnte aber schon wieder angenommen sein, sein aktueller Stand ist nicht "abgelehnt", oder war es jedenfalls nach der Ablehnung zumindest kurz wieder nicht.

`abgelehnt wurde` bedeutet: Der Vertrag ist aktuell abgelehnt.

Comment: _Bevor er reingekommen ist, die Wurst schon gegessen worden war._ - Die Frage: wurde die Wurst eigentlich gegessen oder _ihr aktueller Stand ist nicht "gegessen"?_ ;-)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Der Wurst-Satz funktioniert so nicht (grammatisch). Aber: (1) "Bevor er reinkam, war die Wurst schon geschnitten worden" und (2)"Bevor er reinkam war die Wurst schon geschnitten" haben tatsächlich unterschiedliche Aussagen über den Status der Wurst und der sie betreffenden Tätigkeiten, wenn auch hier die Semantik eines Vertrags und einer geschnittenen Wurst nicht unbedingt parallel liegen... Bei (1) wäre eine weitere 'Bearbeitung' der Wurst (z.B. Essen) möglich und wahrscheinlich, bei (2) liegt die geschnittene Wurst noch rum.

Comment: "Die am Telefon sagten mir, dass der Vertrag **abgelehnt worden war** und auch meine wiederholten Anrufe daran nichts geändert hatten." -> der Vertrag war durchgehend abgelehnt.

Comment: "Die am Telefon sagten mir, dass der Vertrag zuerst **abgelehnt wurde**, sie den Vertragspartner aber dann doch noch überzeugen konnten." -> der Vertrag ist aktuell nicht mehr abgelehnt.